# ASP.NET MVC applied JavaScript to all class

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

i'm working with asp mvc 5

I have a javascript function that applies an action on a given class, for applied this function on a class I use the keyword this by being in this class, my problem is that I do not know how to use this function in any class at the same time,
this is my javascript

```
    function flipCard_1(el, dir) {
    var flipcard = el.closest('div[class|="fsc-comp-flipcard"]');
    if (dir == 1) {
        var card_new_h = flipcard.children('div[class|="fsc-comp-card"]').eq(1).height();
        flipcard.css('height', card_new_h).addClass('flipped');
    }
    else {
        var card_new_h = flipcard.children('div[class|="fsc-comp-card"]').eq(0).height();
        flipcard.css('height', card_new_h).removeClass('flipped');
    }
}
```

I want that el supports any class that FSC-comp-card and applies javascript totu the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var flipcard = el.closest('[class=fsc-comp-flipcard]');
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not using [Class Selector (".class"](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)) properly.

Use

```
el.closest('div.fsc-comp-flipcard')
```

instead of

```
el.closest('div[class|="fsc-comp-flipcard"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

I want change the key word "this" which allow me to apply javascript on the current class, by something which allow me to applie the javascript on all class

```
 <button type="button" class="btn fsc-btn-2" onclick="flipCard_1(jQuery(this), 1);">
```